# ARM instructions, CMP & CMPS

Tags: ассемблер, arm

В общем, дизассемблировал програмку, написанную для ARM7TDMI, и наткнулся на команды CMPS и TSTS.
В официальной документации сказано, что эти команды (TST, CMP, CNP) относятся к командам обработки данных (как ADD, SUB, MOV, MOVN), и в них может указываться флаг "S", который позволяет командам изменять регистр состояния процессора (CPSR). Так вот, по определению команды TST и CMP должны устанавливать флаги сами по себе, а значит, флаг "S" фактически установлен...

Так если следовать логике вещей, то со сброшенным флагом "S", команды TST и CMP вообще не изменяют флагов...
Это так? В чем смысл? Объясните мне, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Нет, даже без флага S инструкция будет скомпилирована так, как будто он был написан. Смысл в том, что большинство команд в машинном коде будет иметь единообразное и простое представление. Документация не говорит, как поведёт себя процессор в случае, если бит S для этих команд не выставлен.

> Certain operations (TST, TEQ, CMP, CMN) do not write the
> result to Rd. They are used only to perform tests and to set
> the condition codes on the result and always have the S bit
> set.